# What is meant by library, package, module and scripts in python

Tags: python

i had read the documentation of python and many sources about the meaning of `package, library, module and script` , i got some and i know thats a basic question but its confusing and very important to know the difference between them.
I know this is basic question but please don't down vote it, because sure this will be useful for others.

Package : which has  `__init__.py` file

Module : Python file that consists of python code

Can anyone explain very easily without confusion between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need a very basic explanation.

What are all you're writing on your own can be called as a **script**.

What are all you're importing in your script can be called as **modules**. Also remember you can make your script as an importable i.e.,module by putting it into a directory which is in python path and contains an `__init__.py` file inside it, considering your script file doesn't contain the `__name='__main__'` as mentioned by Klaus. Now this directory can be called as a **package** as mentioned by Lie.

Another representation - **A package or library** are the set of source files available in pypi or other git repositories that can be build against & installed to your local python version and can be imported as modules in your scripts.

> On the whole, you can write a script, create a package(library) of the
>   same, host it in pypi, download and install it to your python using pip, import
>   as a module in-to an another script.

Answer (score 1):

They all basically mean the same thing, a file or set of files that contains python code, and python makes the distinction between them transparent and therefore less important. But they do have a slightly different meaning.

A "script" is a .py file that is primarily meant to be executed, while a "library" is a  .py file that is primarily meant to be imported by another script. However a single .py file can and are often written both as a script and a library. The timeit module is an example of such script/library duality, if you execute the timeit module from the command line, it takes a command line arguments containing the python code you want to micro benchmark; but you can also import the timeit module to micro benchmark functions or a string to be eval/exec-ed.

Modules is the same thing as library, in that it is primarily meant to be imported, however sometimes people use the word module to refer to a .py file without necessarily implying whether the file is executable (therefore a script) nor import-able (therefore a library). It is a safer word to use if you are not sure whether a file is meant to be executed or imported; or if you want to put less emphasis on the nature of the file; or if you want to refer to a collection of files containing both executable scripts and libraries for importing. It is more neutral word in that sense.

Package specifically refers to `a folder containing an __init__.py` and at least one or more other .py files (technically, a folder that contains only **init**.py is a package as well, but they should just be transformed into a single .py module). A package therefore is a higher hierarchy than modules/libraries.

Comment: TL;DR the distinctions doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

How about this for a starter:

A [module](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) typically is a piece of Python code (i.e. a *script*), which is not interpreted/executed by the PVM at top level, i.e. with `__name ='__main__'`, but imported from the calling script. Definitions from the module thus exist in its own namespace.

This means with other words, that any of your *scripts* may be imported from other pieces of your code and thus act as *modules*.